# For loop within a for loop? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

newbie javascript question. I made sure to research as much as I could before posting here, I've tried many solutions but could be searching for the wrong thing.

I've attached an image below of the issue I have. I'm trying to retrieve everything in the dark blue boxes, but I can't identify those input tags as there is nothing unique about them, I can however identify their parent divs by the class 'f-active'. When the divs have that class they have been selected by the user which is what I am interested in.
[image: page structure]

My attempt so far

```js
var divArray = document.querySelectorAll('div.add-filter.f-active');
var arr = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i < divArray.length; i++){
    var childArray = divArray[i].children;
     // console.log(childArray);
    
    for(var i=0; i < childArray.length; i++){  
      if(childArray[i].tagName == "INPUT"){
        var catNameCollection = arr.push(childArray[i].name);
        // console.log(catNameCollection);
  }
 }
}
```

I tried to use a for loop to get all the parents, then use another for loop to select the children (input tags) and then grab the name attribute, however it is just outputing numbers. I did originally try to create 'divArray' as document.querySelectorAll('div.add-filter.f-active').children, but this and then grab the name attribute in the for loop, but this didn't return anything at all.

Any help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated, I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Your inner loop must use another variable name.

Comment: your `var i` is the same for both loops

Comment: `let` instead of `var` will also fix this :p

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic for-loops usually aren't the best tool for iterating through DOM elements - they add a lot of clutter and are error-prone, especially when you have to nest them.

In your case it'd be simpler to instead modify your query to directly grab all input elements with a div.f-active parent, then extract the names by iterating through them with a forEach. For example (using ES6 or higher):

```
const arr = [];
// Get list of all <input> elements that have <div> element parents with class f-active.
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div.add-filter.f-active > input');
// Extract name from each input element matched by your selector.
nodes.forEach(node => arr.push(node.name));
```

Or if you're stuck using ES5:

```
var arr = [];
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div.add-filter.f-active > input');
nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    arr.push(node.name);
});
```

[Here's a quick JSFiddle I put together to demonstrate the concept for you](https://jsfiddle.net/andfaulkner/4hvq7sbd/). (You'll need to open the console to see the result)

Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: That looks so much better than what I had, unfortunately I'm using GTM to do this which I believe uses ES5, can any of it be translated to ES5 do you think? I tried Babeljs but it resulted in zero ouput :(

Comment: Totally doable. Just added an ES5 solution above and in the JSFiddle. (The arrow function and consts are the only differences here).

Is that working for you?

Answer (score 3):

Your **i** is same for both loops. Use:

```
var divArray = document.querySelectorAll('div.add-filter.f-active');
var arr = [];

  for(var i=0; i < divArray.length; i++){
    var childArray = divArray[i].children;
     // console.log(childArray);

    for(var k=0; k < childArray.length; k++){  
      if(childArray[k].tagName == "INPUT"){
        var catNameCollection = arr.push(childArray[k].name);
        // console.log(catNameCollection);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you hamzox, I've made that change now. The output I'm getting now is not destroying the console which is a great improvement :) However it is now just outputting the number of selected elements rather than the 'name' attribute, any ideas? I'm stumped.